# cURL and Json_encode Call to undefined function Test()

Tags: php, curl

I want to use cURL to send POST data to another server but i get ‘Call to undefined function test()’.
How can i fix it? PS: cURL is already installed and tested in my server.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
set_time_limit(0);
$status = json_decode(test($_POST), true); // (error line) Call to undefined function test()
function test($arra) {
    $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    $arra['ip'] = $ip;
    $ckfile = tempnam("./tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init("site.com/file.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arra);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $c = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $c;
}
```

Comment: Well, you define the function _after_ you try to use it. That means when you try that it is still undefined...

Comment: can you give me a correct format of my code please !

Comment: You certainly should be able to move that function definition further up yourself since this is your code.